Definite integral with high complexity
There are 4 steps for getting the function $ M(m)$.
Step$1$)  :    $f(\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_{N_t-1}) = \frac{1}{K} \prod_{j=1}^{N_t-1} \lambda_j^d e^{-\lambda_j}  \prod_{k>j} (\lambda_j - \lambda_k)^2$
Step$2$) : $f_2(\gamma|\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_{N_t-1}) = f_{21}(\gamma) \bigotimes f_{22}(\gamma)$
$f_{21}(\gamma)  = \sum_{j=1}^{N_t-1} (\prod_{k\neq j} \frac{\lambda_k +s}{\lambda_k-\lambda_j})(\lambda_j+s)e^{-(\lambda_j +s)\gamma} $
$f_{22}(\gamma) = \frac{s^d}{(d-1)!} \gamma^{d-1}e^{-s\gamma}$
Step$3$) $f_3(\gamma) = \int_{0}^{\infty}...\int_{0}^{\infty} f_2(\gamma|\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_{N_t-1}) \times f(\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_{N_t-1}) d\lambda_1 ...d\lambda_{N_t-1}$
Step$4$) $M(m) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-m\gamma}f_3(\gamma)d\gamma$
$K, N_t, N_r ,s, d $ are constants. $d=N_r -N_t +1$. And $\bigotimes$ is convolution.
If, $N_t$ is small value (1 or 2 or 3), the 4 steps can be solved by my hand.
But, If $N_t$ is large value ($N_t > 30$), the complexity is very high.
If $N_t =30$ , $N_r=40$ case, how can i calculate the 4 steps?
What patterns can I find in the process of calculating myself? Or is there any approximation method?
I'm currently implementing 4 steps through symbolic math toolbox in MATLAB, but this is also impossible to execute due to complexity issue. I would appreciate it if you could recommend software that can calculate 4 steps.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
